# Unordered list start with custom number

Tags: css

How can I start my ul list with a custom number, let's say 5.

```
.top_list ul {
list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

would display:
1. 
2.
3. 
....

I want to make the list start at 5. Can i do it?

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it in your HTML:

```
<ol start="5">
  ...
</ol>
```

Comment: hm... (I'm not the OP btw).  This is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#adef-start).  Anyone know the equivalent in css?

Comment: Found this article: http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html. Not sure on it's browser compatibility.

Comment: oh.... that's it then.  See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters

Answer (score 1):

You want `ol`.  `ul` is unordered.

`ol` supports the `start` field, so in the tag you could write

```
<ol start=5>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you per chance mean < ol > as in ordered list?

If you know what to google  a 3 second google search gets you this.

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html

Answer (score 1):

The css property for this (thanks to simshaun for the article) is the `[counter-reset](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters)` property

```
ol.list { counter-reset: item 5 }
```